# How to create a custom drawing in Powerpoint which animates as if it is drawn

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

I need to have a pre-created drawing in my slide. On animating, it should be drawn live on the screen. The drawing is not a straight line. It will be a custom drawing, say an apple.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Well.. I googled a lot. 
Most of the solutions are for Motion Path animation( We can trace a custom path and an object will follow the path).
One other thing I found was Presenter mode. Apparently, using this, we can draw live on the screen when presenting. But unfortunately, I need to have a pre-created drawing.

Comment: Actually, if I draw using the Presenter View, I am able to save the drawing. But I do not know how to animate it to draw itself.

Comment: Not sure PowerPoint supports that. Have you looked at using another program to record you drawing, save it as video and simply play the video in PowerPoint?

Comment: @CharlieRB  Yeah. but given that we are able to save annotations for later use, I assumed Powerpoint would have such a feature built-in. 
I guess I have to just record a video now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not native powerpoint behaviour and I am unaware of any extensions/addons which provide this functionality.

I would recommend you use a screen recorder to capture a video of the screen area you are drawing in and then embed a video into your powerpoint.

Hope this helps